# How to Loop through digits and separate them into single or multiple digits?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to know how to separate and loop through a huge number in C#. For example,

1564758965485698 7458963547589656  i want to write a code that can loop through them and separate them to 16 digits at a time, the output should be:

1564758965485698 
7458963547589656

then i want to mask the digits from both numbers for example:
1564xxxxxx485698
74589xxxxx589656

Then i want to output them to console.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post your code as well?

Comment: As a new user of the site I recommend to read the [help] and please understand that asking someone else to do the work for you is not very appreciated here.

Comment: convert your huge number to a string and then replace the desired characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very simple code should do what you are asking for.

Here is a live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPxYVo

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string temp = "";
        int counter = 0;
        string inputNumber = "15647589654856987458963547589656";

        List<string> batch = new List<string>();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputNumber.Length; i++)
        {   
            counter++;
            temp += inputNumber[i];
            if(counter >= 16)
            {
                batch.Add(MaskedString(temp));
                counter = 0;
                temp = "";
            }
        }

        foreach(var b in batch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }

    public static string MaskedString(string unmaskedString)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(unmaskedString);

        for(int i = 4; i < 9; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Remove(i, 1);
            stringBuilder.Insert(i, "X");
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();        
    }
```